# Html Background-Image Repeat using CSS

Tags: html, css, background

I want to **avoid the repeat of a background image**. It seems something is wrong in the code below because it does not work. It always repeats. I Want `left top no repeat`

Code

```
body {
background: url(../images/bg/bgheleneLogo.JPG)!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-position` Property & `background-repeat` Property

The code will work fine for you

```
body {
background-color: #000000;
background-image: url('../images/bg/bgheleneLogo.JPG');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position-x:top; 
background-position-y:left;  }
```

Comment: Hi Khurram, Thank you very much for your fast respond. I have tried but it does not work perfectly. The situation i have is as follows. I just have the Logo background very small in the top left corner. Ther rest is deep black. At the end the logo should be on the whole area. Hope you can help on this. See the recent situation here: http://www.kinesiologie-hahn.ch Thank you very much.

Comment: You included **25 CSS  Files** , most of them never used in the given page, it might be specific file that is interacting with it...so you need to be specific & with giving specific part of code,